# how to navigate to another page of my website without reloading header in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Till now I have been using GET variable which is passed to the URL when a link/button is clicked, then `index.php` page loads that page.

eg- by default website loads `index.php` page and it includes `header.php`, `home.php`, `footer.php`; when about us button is clicked, GET variable ?page=aboutUs`is passed to URL and then`index.php`includes`aboutUs.php`along with`header.php`and`footer.php`.

But I don't want get variable to be passed, instead I want url to be like `.../home/`  and `.../aboutUs/`

Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .htaccess to craft a rewrite rule.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /$1.php
```

Comment: Thanks, now I don't pass get variable on each button specifically, just the name of page without (.php) .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use rewrite.

Here you could find documentation for [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorDocument 404 /404-error.php
```

Ithink this should work. just redirect like

```
<a href="about">about</a>
```

and the page should be in php like `about.php`